# Inner Join for Multiple Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I would like to use Inner Join for Multiple Row.

I have a table `Company` which has oneToMany relationship with `Market` Table.

```
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Market",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="companys_markets",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $markets;

class Market
{    
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false,unique=true)
     */

    private $name;
```

If set these two classes, Doctrine makes three tables automatically.

And I set data like these below, These means `Company A` belonging to `IT`,`Trans`. `Company B` belonging to `Finance`, `Comapny C` belonging to `It`,`Trans`

```
Company Table
id bane
1  A
2  B
3  C

companys_markets Table
company_id sector_id
1          1
1          2
2          3
3          1
3          2

Sector Table
Id name
1  IT
2  Trans
3  Finance
```

In this case, What I want to have is like this ,every combination of Companys and Sectors

```
A 1
A 2
B 3
C 1
C 2
```

If this relation ship is onetoone I could get like this with `inner join` However, in this case c.markets are multiple, so it doesn't work.

```
$this->em->createQuery(
         "SELECT c.name,c.code,m.name as marketName FROM UserBundle:Company c 
Inner join UserBundle:Market m with m.id = c.markets where c.enabled = true")->getResult()
```

So How can I get these result ??

Comment: What's wrong with the result?

Comment: The result is ideal result. I would like to know how do I get this. @Eric

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I follow what your saying but to get your desired results from the data you provided i did this:

First create temp tables:

```
declare @Company Table ( id int, bane varchar(1) )
insert into @Company values 
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C')

declare @companys_markets Table (company_id int, sector_id int)
insert into @companys_markets values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,3),
(3,1),
(3,2)

declare @Sector Table (Id int, name varchar(40))
insert into @Sector values
(1,  'IT'),
(2,  'Trans'),
(3,  'Finance')
```

Then use this query:

```
select
c.bane,s.Id
from @companys_markets cm
inner join @Company c on cm.company_id = c.id
inner join @Sector s on cm.sector_id = s.Id
```

Gets this result:

```
A   1
A   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
```